# android material design, cardview not added corner radius to phone

Tags: android, xml, material-ui, material-design, android-cardview

I have a Cardview inside android X

```
 <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/card_box_register"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="360dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="226dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
                card_view:cardCornerRadius="36dp"
                card_view:cardElevation="8dp"/>
```

On the surface, everything is fine and tidy, but when I export(apk) the application, none of the corner radius attributes apply to the card view.
To understand more about this, you can look at the photos below
[image: apk]
[image: android studio Preview]

Answer (score 0):

This may be because you have  set the hardware acceleration to false on the manifest(application level) or on the activity level ,if this is the case then add this piece of code to your manifest's application tag

`<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" ...>`

or in your activity level (in the manifest)

```
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
<activity ... />
<activity android:hardwareAccelerated="false" />
```

have a look at the full documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel)

> manifest.xml

```
    <application
        android:name=".application"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".activity.RegisterActivity" />

        <activity
            android:name=".activity.SplashActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Splash">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: can you please share the code to your manifest where the activity was affected